# How to convert a timestamp to an integer (Unix epoch) in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string `"2016-10-25T00:14:30.000"` in PostgreSQL.

I want to convert the timestamp to an integer, e.g: 1477354441

And I want to add custom minutes to that value, e.g. `1477354441+544(minutes) = 1477387081`

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: 1477354441  is not a "timestamp" it's an integer value

Comment: ok then convert to integer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-10-25T00:14:30.000');

SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-10-25T00:14:30.000' + INTERVAL '544 min');
```

Comment: nice, it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination of two functions

```
SELECT 
extract(epoch from to_timestamp('2016-10-25T00:14:30.000','yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mi:ss.ms'))
```