# Postgres format for timestamp in seconds

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

I am creating a table in my PostGres db but the time stamp show as :

```
2015-01-25T22:22:46+08:00
```

I would like to have it show as seconds instead of date .

This is what I have done :

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE api_responses (
        id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        ts timestamp without time zone not null default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
        userid TEXT,
        response JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
        intent TEXT
       );
    ''')
    op.execute('CREATE INDEX ON api_responses (id);')
    op.execute('CREATE INDEX ON api_responses (ts DESC);')


def downgrade():
    op.execute('DROP TABLE api_responses')
```

I didn't find any options to transform now() and get it in seconds

I do not want to do it during the select/extract but automatically through the alembic versioning mecanism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a timestamp to an integer (Unix epoch) in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237197/how-to-convert-a-timestamp-to-an-integer-unix-epoch-in-postgres)

Comment: You're likely look for epoch. Search this page for epoch: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @ScottMarlowe it's not exactly the same because I want to avoid saving in the DB the timestamp as date/time. I have updated the code to show my point. I am using alembic versioning and I try to do it inside this file

Comment: Internally postgresql stores the timestamp as an offset from 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe My bad, I wasn't clear. what I want is a kind of int. link provided seems doing what I want but I try to get it inside the py for alembic/postgres instead of the code who extract the data